# How to format .json file using this package FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

firstly this function will be executed after below code will be execute for formatting code

```
public function formatCode(): bool
{
    $output = [];
    exec(
        'php '.storage_path('php-cs-fixer.phar').' fix  --config='.base_path('.php-cs-fixer.dist.php'), $output);
    
    return true;
}
```

This is my code for the format of all files of my project, I am currently using this package  https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer

```
$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->ignoreVCSIgnored(true)
    ->exclude('tests/Fixtures')
    ->in(__DIR__.'/../laravel8')
    ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
    ->ignoreVCS(true)
    ->append([
        __DIR__.'/dev-tools/doc.php',
      
        __FILE__,
    ]);

$config = new PhpCsFixer\Config();
$config
    ->setRiskyAllowed(true)
    ->setRules([
        '@PSR12' => true, 
])
    ->setFinder($finder);
```

Comment: can you add more detail of what you trying to do ?

Comment: I have one laravel project this code is run through command for formatting all files of my project